# Identify $\operatorname{GL}(2,2)$ with $S_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> List the elements of $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{F}_2)$ and then look at the action of this group on the set of non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{F}^2_2$. Prove this allows you to identify the group $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{F}_2)$ with the symmetric group $S_3$.

So here are all the elements of $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{F}_2)$: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

These are also all non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{F}^2_2$, additionally with $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ since this is also a non-zero vector.

The group $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{F}_2)$ is closed under matrix multiplication since it is a group, so the action of this group on the non-zero vectors represented by these same elements result in elements in this group, so they permute. But with the non-zero vector $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ of $\mathbb{F}^2_2$, if you multiply this with, say, the identity $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, then you get back $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ which is not a permutation since this is not in the group $GL(2, \mathbb{F_2})$. So why is the action the same as the symmetric group $S_3$?

Comment: Sure, you get back the matrix of ones because you acted on it with the identity matrix of your group $GL(2,\mathbb{F})2)$. Now examine the five other (non-identity) matrix of your group, see how they act on each one of the three non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_2^2$.

Comment: $\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$ is not a *vector* in $\Bbb F_2^2$. It is a *matrix* in $\Bbb F_2^{2 \times 2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectors in $\Bbb{F}_2^2$ are not the same as matrices in $\operatorname{GL}(2,\Bbb{F}_2)$. The set of non-zero vectors in $\Bbb{F}_2^2$ is
$$\left\{\binom10,\binom01,\binom11\right\}.$$
Now check how each of the six elements of $\operatorname{GL}(2,\Bbb{F}_2)$ you listed acts on this set. For example
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},$$
permute the first two elements and the last two elements listed above, respectively. What does that tell you about the group they generate?

Comment: I think I am confused about what $\mathbb{F^2_2}$ is. Isn't it two-dimensional vectors? Aren't the three you listed one-dimensional vectors?

Comment: You are then indeed confused. Elements of $\Bbb{F}_2^2=\Bbb{F}_2\times\Bbb{F}_2$ are ordered pairs of elements of $\Bbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$. The one-dimensional vectors are $(0)$ and $(1)$, the two-dimensional vectors are $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: Dimension is a property of the ambient vector **space**, not of a single vector.